# NextJS - Too Many Open Files Error in Production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm facing an issue in my Production environment during peak traffic hours. Any help on identifying the source of this error would be really appreciated.

Error logs -

```
[Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/app/.next/static/chunks/48573ff84b35da845925e086d08de2d8e5ac654c.49c46a48c467dff66cb4.js'] 
[Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/app/.next/static/chunks/8f319b75d6c4fca96c1042484fc0ad01e1047720.aa22673b9cc07604ffb2.js']
```

We're using `getServerSideProps` for server-side rendering.

Tried searching around this issue but most of the people facing this are facing this in NodeJS so not sure exactly how NextJS is managing this behind the scenes.

Production environment -
ECS Fargate (10GB RAM, 4 vCPU), Docker Container, Node-12 Alpine, Next@10.2.2

Comment: Maybe it's Nodejs problem , you check this similar issue https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/613 maybe it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fargate overrides `nofile` resource limit to 1024 by default. Increasing this value could solve `too many open files` problem.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_Ulimit.html

Comment: Yes this is how I eventually solved the problem. Thank you so much.